# How to pronounce $\Sigma_1$?

Tags: logic, pronunciation

I have to give a presentation and part of it involves talking about the recursively enumerable sets. However, some of the theorems I am quoting (like Rosser's proof of Godel's first incompleteness theorem) write $\Sigma_1$-sets instead.

Do I literally pronounce this "Sigma 1 sets"? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's how it usually pronounced. Same goes for $\Pi_1$, $\Delta_1$, higher levels of the hierarchy and relative hierarchies $\Sigma_1^{\mathsf{ZF}}$ etc.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti You should post that as an answer so this moves off the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 4):

The ones with only a subscript are pronounced as they look:

- $\Sigma_1$ : "sigma one"
- $\Pi_n$ : "pi en"

When there is a numerical subscript and a numerical superscript, pronounce the superscript *first*.

- $\Sigma^0_1$ : "sigma zero one"
- $\Pi^1_2$ : "pi one two"
- $\Pi^n_1$ : "pi en one"
- $\Sigma^0_n$ : "sigma zero en"

When the superscript is a set, the pronunciation is more complicated. For example $\Sigma_1^A$ could mean the collection of sets that are $\Sigma_1$ relative to a set $A$. This might be pronounced "sigma 1 in A".

Similarly, $\Sigma^\text{ZF}_1$ might be pronounced "sigma 1 in Z F", "sigma 1 in the language of ZF", or some other way (in general $\Sigma^T_n$ for $T$ a theory is the class of formulas that are provably equivalent in $T$ to a $\Sigma_n$ formula) and, if $C$ is a complexity class, $\Sigma^C_n$ would be "Sigma n C", the $\Sigma_n$ level of the $C$-hierarchy.

Comment: @Andrés: I made this post community wiki - please feel free to add to it. I had not thought much about the (common) example of superscripts that aren't numeric.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I did a minor edit.

Comment: You can also say Sigma Soop Ay Sub Wun for $\Sigma_1^A$.